# Правильно ли использовать display для меню?

Tags: javascript, menu

Простой и краткий вопрос, правильно ли для реального сайта использовать для закрытия и открытия меню `dislay: block/none` корректно это или нужно делать по другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно. А реализации - исходите из Ваших потребностей и удовлетворительности результата.